# How to convert local time into UTC in Hive?

Tags: hive

Can anyone explain to me the following commands:

> from_utc_timestamp
>
> to_utc_timestamp

How can I use these commands in query in Hive?

Also what should be the format of the time?

I want to convert the time into UTC

Thanks for your in advance.

Comment: "Unix Time" is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  How to use these functions is pretty self-explanatory in the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Comment: can you tell me the difference between these 2 commands?